# Assigning Values in R by Date Range

Tags: r, lubridate, as.date

I am trying to create a "week" variable in my dataset of daily observations that begins with a new value (1, 2, 3, et cetera) whenever a new Monday happens. My dataset has observations beginning on April 6th, 2020, and the data are stored in a "YYYY-MM-DD" as.date() format. In this example, an observation between April 6th and April 12th would be a "1", an observation between April 13th and April 19 would be a "2", et cetera.

I am aware of the `week()` package in lubridate, but unfortunately that doesn't work for my purposes because there are not exactly 54 weeks in the year, and therefore "week 54" would only be a few days long. In other words, I would like the days of December 28th, 2020 to January 3rd, 2021 to be categorized as the same week.

Does anyone have a good solution to this problem? I appreciate any insight folks might have.

Comment: It is helpful to understand the problem and your desired behaviour if you add some data and corresponding expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract the dates with the minimum date, divide the difference by 7 and use `floor` to get 1 number for each 7 days.

```
x <- as.Date(c('2020-04-06','2020-04-07','2020-04-13','2020-12-28','2021-01-03'))
as.integer(floor((x - min(x))/7) + 1)
#[1]  1  1  2 39 39
```

Comment: This was a super easy solution to the problem. Thanks so much for helping me out with it.

Answer (score 2):

This will also do

```
df <- data.frame(date = as.Date("2020-04-06")+ 0:365)

library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% group_by(d= year(date), week = (isoweek(date))) %>%
  mutate(week = cur_group_id()) %>% ungroup() %>% select(-d)

# A tibble: 366 x 2
   date        week
   <date>     <int>
 1 2020-04-06     1
 2 2020-04-07     1
 3 2020-04-08     1
 4 2020-04-09     1
 5 2020-04-10     1
 6 2020-04-11     1
 7 2020-04-12     1
 8 2020-04-13     2
 9 2020-04-14     2
10 2020-04-15     2
# ... with 356 more rows
```

Comment: This solved the issue! Thanks so much for the solution, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `lubridate::isoweek()` and `lubridate::isoyear()` is what you want?

Some data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(date = seq.Date(as.Date("2020-04-06"), 
                                  as.Date("2021-01-04"), 
                  by = "1 day"))
```

Example code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df1 <- df1 %>% 
  mutate(week = isoweek(date), 
  year = isoyear(date)) %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  mutate(week2 = 1 + (week - min(week))) %>% 
  ungroup()

head(df1, 8)

# A tibble: 8 x 4
  date        week  year week2
  <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 2020-04-06    15  2020     1
2 2020-04-07    15  2020     1
3 2020-04-08    15  2020     1
4 2020-04-09    15  2020     1
5 2020-04-10    15  2020     1
6 2020-04-11    15  2020     1
7 2020-04-12    15  2020     1
8 2020-04-13    16  2020     2

tail(df1, 8)

# A tibble: 8 x 4
  date        week  year week2
  <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 2020-12-28    53  2020    39
2 2020-12-29    53  2020    39
3 2020-12-30    53  2020    39
4 2020-12-31    53  2020    39
5 2021-01-01    53  2020    39
6 2021-01-02    53  2020    39
7 2021-01-03    53  2020    39
8 2021-01-04     1  2021     1
```

Comment: This worked super well! Thanks so much for the help.